# How to get a value from PHP in Jquery through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

**I'm trying to get a value from a PHP function through Ajax and save it in a variable in jquery.**

The PHP;

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mark_as_read', array( &$this, 'readen_color' ) );

public function readen_color() {
   if( isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['post_id'] ) ) {
      echo 'hello';
   }
}
```

The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert ('Test');
var sArticleId, iPostId;

// Get the article ID and split it - 
sArticleId = $("article").attr('id');
iPostId = parseInt(sArticleId.split('-')[1]);

$.post(ajaxurl, {
 action:'readen_color',
 post_id: iPostId
}, function (response) {
console.log(response);

var response = parseInt(response);
alert('value of response: ' + response);            
});
});
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Could not answer the my own question but
Now it works with:

```
var responsevar = response;
alert('The Server Responses: ' + responsevar);
```

Instead of:

```
var response = parseInt(response);
alert('value of response: ' + response);
```

Comment: Are you doing this in the admin or on a public page?

Comment: @totels in functions.php and public page [live example](http://www.maurer-newmedia.ch/dynamics-nav/cal/einfuhrung/operatoren/)

Comment: You'll need to use `wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)` for ajax on a public page.

Comment: More details [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).

Comment: @totels before the test alert printed 0. Now it Prints NaN..?

Comment: You can answer your own questions just not that fast :)

Comment: @Bainternet in 7 hours OMG.. =) what now if i wanna pass an Array? should i make a new question for that?

Comment: Aside from performing the functionality within an action hook callback (which provides the *context* but not the *point* of the question), this question is not specific to WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing 'readen_color' as the action parameter, but you've defined the ajax action as 'mark_as_read'.

Try this:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, {
    action:'mark_as_read',
    post_id: iPostId
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

And as for your PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mark_as_read', array( &$this, 'readen_color' ) );
// Add no_priv if you want users not logged in to be able to call the function.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_mark_as_read', array( &$this, 'readen_color' ) );

public function readen_color() {
    if( isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['post_id'] ) ) {
        // You must call die to avoid the trailing 0 in the response.
        die('hello');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### AJAX & "localized" data

Originally passing data from PHP to JS was only meant to be used with localization, hence the function name. Nowadays it's widely accepted, that you can use it to transfer data as well for AJAX calls. Here's an example on how to "localize" a script - alias: Get data from php to JS.

```
$this->handle = 'awesomescript';
$this->action = 'awesomeaction';

wp_enqueue_script(
     $this->handle
    ,plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/js/ajax.js'
    ,array(
         'jquery'
        ,'jquery-ui-autocomplete'
     )
    ,filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/js/ajax.js' )
    ,true
);

wp_localize_script(
     $this->handle
    ,"{$this->handle}_obj"
    ,array(
         'ajaxurl'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        ,'_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( $this->nonce )
        ,'action'     => $this->action
        ,'data'       => array(
             'some_key'  => $some_value
            ,'other_key' => $some_other_value
         )
        ,'debug'      => $this->debug_js
     )
);
```

_Note: This is taken from a class from one of my plugins, so you'll have to replace the `$this->foo` parts with your own.

If you then want to pass data with AJAX, simply register a callback to your action (private/admin or public):

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_{$this->action}", array( $this, 'ajax_cb' ) );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_{$this->action}", array( $this, 'ajax_cb' ) );
```

Then you can easily modify your result (or do a query or whatever comes into your mind).

### Retrieve in JS

Now you're able to call `awesomescript_obj` in your localized script file and have access to all the data (incl. those in the `data` container/array).